# Spoof-proof Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I'm working on a web app which must measure the time user needs to do something. I can't simply use javascript time object, because the user may change system time to cheat and fool the app. I'd need some way to prevent this.

Comment: There might be a publicly available web service that provides accurate time, but it could still be spoofed if the user changes his/her locale settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the web app send heartbeats or any other form of signals back to the server side. Then you can construct some metrics like `duration = end - start`

Accounting for the round trip client-server communication, this isn't suitable for ms resolution measurements, obviously.

**Note :** It's not a good idea to just read the time from a "trusted" web service into your client side app, you can't really guarantee the app wouldn't temper with it. (One of cardinal rules in client side dealings, is to not trust its input, e.g. for validation, you still need server-side validation on top). However if you just send signals to the server, log its timestamp using the server's clock, you are a lot safer.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate time on the **server** side.

The client user cannot futz with that (at least they should not be able to)

Comment: Serious question, wouldn't this just be kicking the can down the road? What's to prevent the client from sending the "all finished" at an arbitrary time?

Comment: @ultranaut yes... but you can check the server time to make sure they are allowed to send the data

Comment: @ultranaut: I can just fetch starting and finishing time from the server to prevent this.

Comment: @Neal not sure what you mean about checking to make sure they are allowed to send the data. If I'm the client and the task actually takes two seconds, what's to prevent me from sending the data at one second in instead. How's the server going to determine a time is legit or not?

Comment: Unless of course the client is returning some sort of answer or something that proves they've finished whatever the task is.

Answer (score 3):

Then you have to do it on the **server side**. Everything that happens on the client is manipulable.
One way would be to do ajax calls and measure the time in php or other server sided scripts.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this depends upon what time measurement accuracy you need.

If you are measuring long times (a minute or longer) and just need accuracy to within a minute, then using an ajax call to fetch a remote server time is clearly a more foolproof way than any client-side clock measurements.

If you are trying to measure shorter times in under a minute, then you will need to use the local clock to achieve any sort of accuracy.  For that, you can check if the local computer's clock has been messed with using the following type algorithm:

1. Send a remote request to a server to get the current time.  This could be either a publicly available time resource or your own server.
2. Get the current time on the local computer.
3. Calculate the offset between those two times.  What you are looking for is that there is no significant change in the offset.
4. Using local computer time, mark the start of the local operation
5. User does their operation.
6. Get current time on the local computer to mark the end of the local operation
7. Get remote time again.
8. Get the current time on the local computer
9. Calculate the offset between local and server time.  Allowing for a small difference in the amount of time it took to retrieve the remote time, see if the difference is relatively the same as the previously calculated difference.  If this difference is not the same, then the local clock has been messed with.

Note, because you can't instantaneously get the remote time (there is always an indeterminate delay time in retrieving it), there is an inherent inaccuracy here of a few seconds in verifying that the local clock has not been messed with.  The inaccuracy is not in measuring the local operation, just in verifying that the local clock hasn't been messed with.

So ... this technique works best for detecting clock manipulations that are more than a few seconds, not smaller manipulations.